# Let $f:(0,1)→R$ be continuous. Pick out the statements which imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f :(0, 1)→ R$ be continuous. Pick out the statements which imply
that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

a. $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ \sqrt{|x − y|}, \text{ for all }x, y \in [0, 1].$

b.  $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\rightarrow \frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: It is even discontinuous in $0$ about the $f$ in $(b)$. And $f$ in $(a)$ satisfies Lipschitz Condition so it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Domain of function is open (0,1)

Comment: Lemma. $f$ is uniformly in $(a,b)$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ the limits of $a,b$ are exist. Then you can extend the function on whole $[a,b]$.

Comment: If |f(x)−f(y)|≤k.|x−y|, then f satisfies lipscitz condition, in a it is not satisfied- gaoxinge

Comment: En, you are right. I didn't notice it.

Comment: give a proper verification for case (b).

Comment: (b) can't even happen. If $f(1/n) \to 1/2$, then for $n$ big enough $f(1/n) > 3/8$. In particular for $n$ big enough $f(1/n^2) > 3/8$, and so $f(1/n^2)$ can't converge to $1/4$.

Comment: I think the condition of $(a)$ is to make sure that $f$ is continuous in $(0,1)$ and have limits on $0,1$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous  in $[0,1]$ and removing two points $0,1$, it is also right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For option $(b)$ does not  implies that uniform convergence.
Take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.Here $a_n-b_n \rightarrow 0$ but $f(a_n)-f(b_n)\nrightarrow 0$ . Hence (b) does not implies uniform continuity.

Comment: please read the question Murugan

Comment: See! suppose (b) implies f is uniformly continuous. Then if we take a seqn $a_n $ and $b_n$ as the above. By uniform continuity $f(a_n)-f(b_n)$ goes to zero. so contradiction.

Comment: sorry my mistake. thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that "does not imply" is, technically, the wrong answer to part b) in view of nik's comment above.  E.g. doesn't $1 = 2$ imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Notice this

> $$ |f(x) − f(y)| ≤ \sqrt{|x − y|} < \epsilon \implies |x-y|< \epsilon^2 = \delta.  $$

Comment: what about option b?

Comment: impossible since $n^2$ is a subsequence of $n$

Comment: Mhenni Benghorbal can you give me a conterexample or proper justification for case b in your answer?